# ImportError: cannot import name 'CUDF_INSTALLED' from 'xgboost.compat'

Tags: python, anaconda, xgboost

Good evening.

I just helped someone with an xgboost install via anaconda, by using the line:

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

And the line in the title is what I was given:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'CUDF_INSTALLED' from 'xgboost.compat' (/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xgboost/compat.py)
```

Google does not provide a lot of insight with respect to how to handle this particular error message.

What would be causing this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed xgboost with using:

```
brew install xgboost
```

Then I got the same error. Close all running jupyter notebooks and restart anaconda. It works for me.